# How to create generic implicit conversions for json marshalling

Tags: scala, types, marshalling

I want to limit the construction of a case class to certain types and then be able to marshall that data back and forth.

For example, let's say I have a "home" case class that takes in a "kind" argument. I want to restrict the "kind" argument to a list of approved housing types, e.g., Apartment, Condo, etc.

```
object Home {
  // this will create an implicit conversion to json object
  implicit lazy val jsFormat = Jsonx.formatCaseClass[Home]
}

case class Home(owner: String, kind: HousingType)
```

What I need now is a way to marshall the various child types of `HousingType`. For example, here are some relationships:

```
trait HousingType

case object Apartment extends HousingType

case object Condo extends HousingType
```

Predictably, attempting to use this without specifying an implicit conversion yields the following error:

```
"could not find implicit value for parameter helper: ... HousingType"
```

Is there a way to create a generic implicit conversion for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify how your JSON marshaller has to transform your `case object`, as you have `case class`, it's quite simple for `JSON marshaller` to follow default behavior - take JSON field names from a `case class` and their type.

You need to indicate how to marshall/unmarshall `case object` directly, for instance via an implicit conversion.

```
  implicit object HousingTypeMarshaller extends Writes[HousingType] {
    def writes(housingType: HousingType) = housingType match {
      case Apartment => Json.toJson("Apartment")
      case Condo => Json.toJson("Condo")
    }
  }
```

p.s. I use usual play.json in this example because I didn't find any reason to use  `Jsonx`, suggest you faced a limitation on 22 fields with `Play Json`, usual `Play Json` is suitable for this situation with `case object`.